# How to compare django object and string in templates

Tags: python, django

i want to know how to compare an object with a string in templates. Do in need to do it in views.py or in my html templates.

my views.py

```
 permission = permission_group_sas.objects.all()

    context_dict = {

        'permission':permission,
        # 'groups':groups,

        }  

    return render_to_response(template, RequestContext(request, context_dict))
```

my html

```
{% for user in user.groups.all %}                  

                        {% for value in permission %}

                        <h4>1. {{ user.name }}

                        <p>2. {{ value.group }}</p></h4>

                        {% if value.group  == user.name %}

                        OK!!

                        {% endif%}                                        
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

value.group is an object and user.name is a string. So the word OK!! does not appear in my screen What is the correct way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: what about `value.group.attribute_here`

Comment: in my templates or views??

Comment: i tried value.group.attribute_here.. nothing happen..

Comment: What attribute from group do you want to compare with user.name?

Comment: owh.. ok ok.. let me try..

Comment: You are comparint with the django templates. so no html work needed. 
Try str(value.group) to convert to string and compare with user.name